# Export part of the output of NMinimize into file.csv

Tags: export, mathematical-optimization, output-formatting

After an optimisation procedure ([`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)), I want to save the results in a *"file.csv"*.

The format of the output is:

```
output = NMinimize[{f, constraints}, v,  Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]

output = {6.7303, {X[1] -> 2.99573, X[2] -> 2.50572, X[3] -> 2.35682, 
 ... , X[10] -> 5.27534}}
```

I want to save only the values of X[i] in a format as follow:

```
{2.99573, 2.50572, 2.35682, ... , 5.27534}
```

It is possible?

Comment: Use `NArgMin[]`.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. (Notice the links)

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Function to [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
func = Product[(x[i] - RandomReal[])^2, {i, 4}]
```

> ```
> (-0.675982 + x[1])^2 (-0.802735 + x[2])^2 (-0.0478063 + x[3])^2 (-0.350573 + x[4])^2
> ```

Minimisation with [`NArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMin.html), equivalent to  `{x,y,…}/.Last[NMinimize[…,{x,y,…},…]`

```
out = NArgMin[func, Array[x, 4]]
```

> ```
> {0.675982, 0.802735, 0.0478064, 0.350573}
> ```

Save the output with [CSV format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html)

```
Export["file.CSV", out]
```